# SyncObjects does not contain definition for "Item" Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

Trying to use a function to refresh my outlook mailbox (receive any new mail).  I am getting `SyncObjects does not contain definition for "Item"`.  on line `syncObj = syncObjs.Item(i);` What is the issue with my code?  This example I found online.

```
    private void AlternativeWay()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.SyncObjects syncObjs = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.SyncObject syncObj = null;
        try
        {
            //ns = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            ns = mapiNameSpace;
            syncObjs = ns.SyncObjects;
            for (int i = 1; syncObjs.Count >= i; i++)
            {
                syncObj = syncObjs.Item(i);
                
                if (syncObj != null)
                {
                    syncObj.Start();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(syncObj);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (syncObjs != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(syncObjs);
            if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In .net based programming languages you need to use [indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) instead:

```
private void AlternativeWay()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.SyncObjects syncObjs = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.SyncObject syncObj = null;
        try
        {
            //ns = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            ns = mapiNameSpace;
            syncObjs = ns.SyncObjects;
            for (int i = 1; syncObjs.Count >= i; i++)
            {
                syncObj = syncObjs[i];
                
                if (syncObj != null)
                {
                    syncObj.Start();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(syncObj);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (syncObjs != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(syncObjs);
            if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
        }
    }
```